# Custom Layout of ListFragment is not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I tried to use a ListFragment with a custom layout: Simple static headline, below the ListContent given with the SimpleCursorAdapter. The list itself also has a custom layout. The SimpleCursorAdapter works (Query is fine, Custom Layout for List works). As long as I do not use custom layout for the Fragment itself, everything works fine.
If I add the layout for the Fragment, only the headline (Textview) works, the list keeps empty.

Custom Layout for the List:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp" >
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/value"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:textSize="20sp" >
</TextView>
```

Custom Layout for the Fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/last_update"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</TextView>
<ListView
    android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</ListView>
<TextView android:id="@id/android:empty"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:background="#FF0000"
           android:text="No data">
</TextView>
```

I commented some stuff out - it was worth a try because i read that it helped - for me it was not helping.

Last bot not least the Code of the Fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewfragment, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    TableDataGateway tableGate = new TableDataGateway(getActivity());
    tableGate.UpdateUIRecords();
    TextView tv = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.last_update);
    tv.setText(tableGate.getLastUpdateDate());
    Cursor cursor = tableGate.selectUIRecords();

    dBadapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.viewlayout, cursor, new String[] { DB_COL_GUI_LABEL, DB_COL_LAST_KNOWN_VALUE }, new int[] { R.id.label, R.id.value }, 0);
    super.setListAdapter(dBadapter);

}
```

Question is: Why is the ListAdapter not connecting with the fragment layout?

Regards

Flizz

**CLARIFICATION OF THE PROBLEM**
I have a similar problem like [Android + ListFragment with a custom view hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7533934/android-listfragment-with-a-custom-view-hierarchy?rq=1)
But i do not have stacked the content over each other, i only see the TextView content in the top corner of the screen and below where the list should be is just a white background.
I was pretty sure to have done anything as Google told to do (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html keyword Screen Layout)

Update:
I am unsure whether i have to change my main_activity.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have not considered the fragment in there, do not know whether this is needed. Yesterday i tried a few functions to understand my problem in detail. I used getView().isShown() and get the return FALSE - this seems wrong to my, but I have no clue what is wrong here ...

Comment: Have you defined the ListView in the `onCreate`? I see nothing as such is defined? You need to set you adapter to the listview and on the super!

Comment: and you cant override id names with default android name.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean?
In the function onActivityCreated i execute

`super.setListAdapter(dBadapter);`

Comment: As far as I understood, Fragments have no onCreate method, only the onCreateView method in which I already return the custom layout.
SetContentView is not applicable in fragments, at least I do not know what I have to import to get access to it.

Comment: You can use `getView()` to access the running activity for the fragment.

Comment: Sorry man, I appreciate your help, but the breadcrump trail is not leading to anything for me, could you please get into more detail?
From what I understand, it might be caused by a wrong context I give the SimpleCursorAdapter?
Sorry but I really do not know what you are going for - I also cannot recognize any of your hints in the examples I found so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing
[Blank ListView with SimpleCursorAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20877864/blank-listview-with-simplecursoradapter)
http://developer.android.com/samples/CustomChoiceList/src/com.example.android.customchoicelist/MainActivity.html
http://developer.android.com/samples/CustomChoiceList/res/layout/sample_main.html

i found the solution - everything is right so far. I just messed up the layout file:
Both contents ListView as TextView had the value "match_parent" - so there was not enough layout room for the other component. The component which comes first in the layout file overwrites everything else.
I adjusted the layout file to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1">
</ListView> 
<TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:background="#FF0000"
           android:text="No data">
</TextView>

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/last_update"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and everything works fine. Do **NOT** use the fragment layout for the activity - it should have its own layout, else it will lead to errors.
Thanks everybody for helping.

Rgds

Flizz

Answer (score 0):

Your ListView id must be @android:id/list in a ListFragment. 
Maybe you should also replace super.setListAdapter to just setListAdapter.

Comment: Hasn't worked. Either any combination of the layout id nor the super changed something.

Comment: Sorry, no it is not - my bad. I still cannot see the list content while using custom fragment layout.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Here is a snippet of correct usage of CustomAdapter:

```
private class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private ArrayList<String> mData = new ArrayList<String>();
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public MyCustomAdapter() {
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        public void addItem(final String item) {
            mData.add(item);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
          if(position < LIST_ITEM_TYPE_1_COUNT)
              return LIST_ITEM_TYPE_1;
          else
              return LIST_ITEM_TYPE_2;
        }

        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {
            return LIST_ITEM_TYPE_COUNT;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mData.size();
        }

        @Override
        public String getItem(int position) {
            return mData.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder = null;
            int type = getItemViewType(position);
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                switch(type) {
                    case LIST_ITEM_TYPE_1:
                        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_type1, null);
                        holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_type1_text_view);
                        break;
                    case LIST_ITEM_TYPE_2:
                        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_type2, null);
                        holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_type2_button);
                        break;
                }
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.textView.setText(mData.get(position));
            return convertView;
        }

    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView textView;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey,

thank you. I will try it this evening with your code. A question pops up in my mind reading this: Do I made my problem understandable? I do not have a problem with the Adapter - it works fine and displays the content in the viewlayout.xml-style.
My problem is, that I want the Fragment to show 2 things -> a textview (last_update) and the list from the Adapter. Only if I use this custom Fragment layout (viewfragment), I cannot see the data of the Adapter.

Comment: I tried to implement this, but there are constants I do not have a clue what value they should have. I made a clarification in the upper text - do you think this will solve the problem? My adapter seems to work fine, it just does not connect to the layout ...Appreciate your help!
Do you think something in my Activity is wrong?